# Search a place offline with openstreetmap on android emulator

Tags: android, emulation, openstreetmap

I would like to search a place with the android emulator. I use openstreetmap and I want to do it offline! 
Can someone tells me how to do it! I would like to send a name or a restaurant for example and to have the position of this on on the map but offline!

I don't know if it can help but I have already an KML and GPX file but no librairie, for the moment, I'm using osmbonuspack because I've used osmdroid and mapnik to display the map 
Help me please!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [list of OSM apps and libraries for Android](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android) in the OSM wiki.

KML and GPX files probably won't help. Likewise, osmdroid is neither capable of displaying maps nor of performing geocoding requests when used offline.